# Error: Could not find MyFirstApp.apk

Tags: android, eclipse

I am following he tutorial from this site: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html, but when I run the default program in eclipse when an android project is created, it gives me the error R could not be found. To fix this, I commented out the lines with R and ran it again, but now it gives me the error: Could not find MyFirstApp.apk!... I have tried all other solutions on this site, but none of them work. If anybody knows how to fix this, please let me know![image: Image of error]

here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: did you define your activity in the manifest?

Comment: you mean like this line: android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"?

Comment: the R class is not generated when you have some issues in your layouts or manifest. can you share some code? for example the whole manifest xml?

Comment: I added it in my original question, please take a look at that

Comment: Please? I really need an answer to this question

Comment: Try a Project->Clean.

Comment: No dice... I have tried virtually everything else on this website concerning this problem without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your .R class could not be found, there is an error in your project - commenting out the lines with the .R class does not fix the problem.

Perhaps you just have to clean your workspace (Project > Clean...) or delete the bin and gen folder in your project, they should be rebuilt automatically.

Look at the Problems tab next to the Console tab where you get the errors and take a look at the messages.

Comment: First off, I do not have a bin folder in my project. Second off, I deleted the gen folder, did a clean, and now it is not coming back. Any advice?

Comment: Do you have this line in your code? If not, add it to the other imports: import com.example.myfirstapp.R;

Comment: nope, i ran it directly after it was created, and it gave me the errors about R being not found

Comment: Have you installed the SDK Build tools? Start the SDK Manager and look if the Build Tools for your SDK version (I see it's 19) are installed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42722/discussion-between-julia-hexen-and-quixotrykd)

Comment: Perhaps you just solved it but I copied your XML code and there are some semicolons - delete them and add "http://" to the both schema urls.

Comment: nope... that was just an issue with my copy and pasting it. Stack Overflow must have done that automatically, my real code has http:// and no semicolons

Comment: This is really strange... Have you tried to create a new workspace and generate an Android project again?

Comment: Nope, I made a brand new workspace and the exact same problem occured. I noticed however that the gen folder is empty, could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Can you pick a screenshot what you have installed with Android SDK Manager?

Comment: here you go![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wLrEi.png) this is a picture of the SDK stuff I have installed, see any problems?

Comment: This is really a hard case ^^ Is everything fine with the build path (right click on project > Properites > Java Build Path)? Have you tried right click on project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties? Completely restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

when I had originally installed the android sdk it installed to some folder in my filesystem. I moved the SDK manager to a folder on my desktop, and installed updates through there. I had to change my android path to that folder, and everything fixed! Thanks for your help though, it was much appreciated.

Comment: Where did you change the Android path?